Concurrency and Multi-threading
How can one implement a custom ReadWriteLock in Java that allows a thread to upgrade a read lock to a write lock without risking deadlock?

If two threads ask for this upgrade at the same time, one of them has to fail to the point that the operation returns an error/throws an exception (because you need it to let go of its read lock or the whole thing will get stuck). And that's more or less it.

Ensuring that there is only one thread using the lock at all times, but that is not realistic.
